# to redirect the same page after form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form in my webpage Index.html. When I submit my form it redirects to the action page.

I want the page to redirect to itself (index.html) after completing the action.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row marginbot-80">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="mailfunc.php" class="wow bounceInUp" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                <div class="row marginbot-20">
                    <div class="col-md-6 xs-marginbot-20">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required="required" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="25" required="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button "style=width:40 height:40" class="btn btn-skin" type="submit" id="btnContactUs">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should achieve this on your mailfunc.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redirect after the script in `mailfunc.php` to your index.html like this:

```
header("Location: index.html");
exit();
```

Comment: thanks..it works..
i have many things in my webpage like about us,what do we do, our team ,and the last part is contact us...  your solution redirects me on the beginning of the page...but i want to redirect on that contact form (where i hit the send message button)

Comment: Is the contact us part of the index.html? If so, you could make it an anchor tag. and then redirect to `index.html#contact`

Answer (score 0):

Currently your submit will open a POST request to mailfunc.php where your form data (most probably) will be processed.

You can quite easily forward from mailfunc.php to index.html using some Javascript code like:

```
window.location.href = 'index.html';
```

Comment: i don't know where tand how to use this piece of code you gave .
 i have many things in my webpage like about us,what do we do, our team ,and the last part is contact us... your solution redirects me on the beginning of the page...but i want to redirect on that contact form (where i hit the send message button)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

header("Location: $referer");
```

This helps you to redirect to the same page where you are submitting the form

Refer this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-referer/) to know more about HTTP_REFERER

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).